# Календарь Битрикс24 и Python

Tags: python, rest, битрикс24

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отправить данные, полученные Telegram-ботом, в Календарь Битрикс24 на Python

Отправить нужно данные по абстрактному примеру:

```
name = Иван
number = 111111111
day = *выбранная дата*
time = *выбранное время*
```

На указанный день в Календаре Битрикс24 должно отобразиться полученное имя и номер телефона

Буду очень благодарна за помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть библиотека для работы с битрикс24.  Например

```
from bitrix24 import *

bx24 = Bitrix24()#<---- Здесь метод для вызова rest api в Битрикс24, найди его в панели для разработчиков
            try:

                #Добавляем события битрикс 
                

                bx24.callMethod('calendar.event.add', fields={'name':name,#Наименование события.
                                                          'from':day, #Дата начала выборки.
                                                          'to': day, #Дата окончания выборки.
                                                           'description': number # Описание события, сюда и запиши телефон
})


            except BitrixError as message:
                print(message)
            print('Успешно выполнено!')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду пробовать!